# Is it ok if req.user of passport.js leak?

Tags: node.js, security, passport.js

Is it okay if the req.user variable used by passport is leaked?

For example, I wonder if it is possible to set the member number as req.user and use it as a nickname or identification number.

+
I want to make profile page. And that link will be sitename.com/profile/124102515(req.user value) Can I use this method?

Comment: can you please explain littile bit more. how req.user can be leaked?  you are sending back req param with response?

Comment: I want to make profile page. And that link will be http://sitename.com/profile/124102515(req.user value)
Can I use this method?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: HTTP headers including the URL used for GET / POST should be protected by TLS, so **are** you really leaking the profile name? It doesn't seem cryptographically secure either, so it is probably easy to guess a username. I presume you don't just rely on the user ID for authentication if you're using an authentication framework. Not using TLS is out of the question nowadays.